# Nginx upload installation error

Tags: file-upload, nginx, tornado

I am on Mac OSX Lion using Nginx 1.4.1. I am using nginx in conjunction with Tornado.

In the process of installing the Nginx upload module (v. 2.2.0) I encountered some compatibility issues. See  [this reference](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/issues/41)  for more info. Apparently, there is no great fix for this as of yet. My specific error is rooted in: `error: no member
      named 'to_write' in 'ngx_http_request_body_t'`

1. Is there a way to make the two of these reliably compatible without jumping through hoops?
2. Or, is there a suitable alternative to using this upload module that will work with Nginx 1.4.1?
3. If not, should I considering using Nginx 1.3.8? And if so, where can I download this version? I do not see it available for download on their website [here](http://nginx.org/en/download.html).

Thank you for the help. Regards.

Comment: The incompatibility between the upload module and the main body doesn't seem to be an easy fix. Did you try the latest dev version 1.5.0? http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Development

Comment: I have not done that yet, but I will give it a try to see if it solves anything. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, it doesn't seem like there is as the maintainer of nginx-file-upload has implied [he doesn't want to maintain it any more](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module/issues/41#issuecomment-15692917).

2) I found this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw) which lists some alternatives. One of which is [nginx-big-upload](https://github.com/pgaertig/nginx-big-upload) I've not tried it yet.

3) Well you could consider it but then you're tied in to a package that isn't maintained. What happens if there's a security vulnerability for 1.3.8? You can't upgrade without either patching or changing your file upload strategy. If you want to, you can find [all of the older Nginx versions here](http://nginx.org/download/)

The situation is pretty frustrating at the moment but there are options, just none of them are tried and true. When dealing with production systems stability and security are key.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, this module dose not support for nginx 1.4+.

2) The reason is that nginx support chunked of thansfer-encode, and improve its code design. that it remove the field to_write of ngx_http_request_body_t struct.

3) https://github.com/hongzhidao/nginx-upload-module. This is an alter module. It support the latest nginx, and the feature is equal.